Why do I get "no such function:SQRT" when I run my query?
When I run a query with sqlite3 in Python 3.10 it raises exception:

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function:SQRT

sqlite3.version_info shows 2.6.0 and sqlite3.sqlite_version shows 3.45.3. How can I run my SQL query successfully?

How do you expect us to help without seeing the full code?

Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

This question is similar to: Python SQLite math functions (no such function: SQRT). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's possible the version of sqlite you're using was built without math functions for some reason.

Please try the following commands one by one in your python3-console (in this case I'm using Python 3.10.6):
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()
res = cur.execute("SELECT SQRT(2)")
res.fetchone()

In my case it returns:
'3.37.2'                   as result of sqlite_version
(1.4142135623730951,)      as result of fetchone

